# How to change the name of a subdomain with an another name domain?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, dns, subdomain

I want to change the name of my subdomain which is subdomain.olddomain.com (wordpress) to a name domain that I have bought on LWS, https://newdomain.com.

I would like to keep all website in the server which has the subdomain but call with https://newdomain.com.

It is possible ?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah it is possible,

you have to link your new domain to the server which have the subdomain from the domain provider

then change the apache conf where server name property become newdomain,

restart apache, wait a little bit for the modification on your domain provider to propagate and all is good

Comment: thank you,
1) you have to link your new domain to the server which have the subdomain from the domain provider.
ans : In the dns zone of the he domain provider, I put the IP of my subdomain ?  A @ subdomain.olddomain.com<--IP
2)then change the apache conf where server name property become newdomain
ans:  ServerName subdomain.olddomain.com by ServerName newdomain.com
It's right ?

Comment: I have SSL in the new domain, it will be automatically added?

Comment: No, you have to create a new certificate, look at certbot if you dont know how to do it : https://certbot.eff.org/